# Disable-devtool in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, devtools, disable

I am currently building an app in **Next.js** and I want to disable opening devtools. I found a nice package on npm - *Disable-devtool - [npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/disable-devtool)* but the problem is that nextjs keeps throwing me `ReferenceError: navigator is not defined`. I tried to look into node_modules but didn't find any solution whatsoever, any help please?

Thank you ❤️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    if (
        typeof window !== "undefined" &&
        typeof window.navigator !== "undefined" &&
        typeof navigator !== "undefined" &&
        navigator.userAgent
    ) {
        const disableDevtool = require("disable-devtool");
        disableDevtool();
    }
```

Comment: yes, thanks it kinda helps but overall I think nextjs has some sort of incompatibility with this package xd... I managed to just copy the <script> tag and inserted it to my _document.js and it works just fine :D